# Downloading image in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, download, save-as

I want to upload a photo after clicking the button. I have a link to upload a photo, for example, https://unsplash.com/photos/qPDyWI5JFcI/download.

In HTML i have:

```
<button
  class="button-more"
  @click.stop="onDownloadClick(card.links.download_location)"
>
  Download
</button>
```

In Vue file I do:

```
import FileSaver from 'file-saver'

methods: {
  onDownloadClick(downloadLink) {
      axios({
      url: downloadLink,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'blob',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Client-ID ${process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_KEY}`
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([response.data]), 'image.jpeg')
    })
  }
}
```

But after uploading the photo I get:

[image: Result afret uploading]

I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: Can you confirm if you have CORS access? I tried to reproduce your problem and got `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://unsplash.com/photos/qPDyWI5JFcI/download' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'unsplash.com'`

Comment: The error says `Not a PNG file`. You are trying to save it under the name of `image.jpg`. Maybe there is a conflict between `.png` and `.jpg` and that's a problem?

Comment: I tried other types and the same problem. I have access when i passed my access code  here
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Client-ID ${process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_KEY}`
      }